# How can receive user's input date and match it with the date() javascript function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a simple calendar/events app. User should be able to enter the date (or dates) of the event an then the event would display in the correct dates.

This is my failed attempt to do it. Any help will be appreciated:

How I receive user's input:

```
<div className="event">
  <select
    className="dateDropdown"
    onChange={this.props.handleChange}
    name={this.props.day}
  >
    <option value="">Day</option>
    <option value="1">01</option>
    <option value="2">02</option>
    <option value="3">03</option>
    <option value="4">04</option>
    <option value="5">05</option>
    <option value="6">06</option>
    <option value="7">07</option>
    <option value="8">08</option>
    <option value="9">09</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="26">26</option>
    <option value="27">27</option>
    <option value="28">28</option>
    <option value="29">29</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="31">31</option>
  </select>
  <select
    className="dateDropdown"
    name={this.props.month}
    onChange={this.props.handleChange}
  >
    <option value="">Month</option>
    <option value="0">Jan</option>
    <option value="1">Feb</option>
    <option value="2">Mar</option>
    <option value="3">Apr</option>
    <option value="4">May</option>
    <option value="5">Jun</option>
    <option value="6">Jul</option>
    <option value="7">Aug</option>
    <option value="8">Sept</option>
    <option value="9">Oct</option>
    <option value="10">Nov</option>
    <option value="11">Dec</option>
  </select>

  <select className="dateDropdown" onChange={this.props.handleChange}>
    <option value="2019">2019</option>
    <option value="2020">2020</option>
  </select>
</div>;
```

I defined the date variable:

```
let date = new Date();
```

How I display the events in the right place (today, tomorrow, etc). I'm sure this is wrong because if today's UTC day is 31, TOMORROW div will try to find day 32, which of course does not exist:

```
<div className="dayDiv">
  <p className="text day">TODAY</p>
  <div className="eventsDiv">
    {this.state.events &&
      this.state.events.map(data => {
        if (date.getUTCDate() === data.day && date.getMonth() === data.month) {
          return <Event data={data} />;
        }
      })}
  </div>
</div>;

<div className="dayDiv">
  <p className="text day">TOMORROW</p>
  <div className="eventsDiv">
    {this.state.events &&
      this.state.events.map(data => {
        if (
          date.getUTCDate() + 1 === data.day &&
          date.getMonth() === data.month
        ) {
          return <Event data={data} />;
        }
      })}
  </div>
</div>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new object from the new (tomorrow) date, using `new Date(year, month, day + 1)`, and this returns a new Date object with tomorrow's date. For more information check official MDN documentation about [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

```js
let today = new Date();
let tomorrow = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() + 1);

console.log(today.getDate()); // Getting today's date
console.log(tomorrow.getDate()); // Getting tomorrow's date
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a dedicated input type for the dates in HTML5 it has the following syntax:

```html
<label for="start">Start date:</label>
<input type="date" id="start" name="trip-start"
       value="2018-07-22"
       min="2018-01-01" max="2018-12-31" />
```

this will help you with the event component to get a valid date since it can handle all date-related stuff like if the month is 28,29,30, or 31 days